# Filtering Data in all pages of an paginated external api

Tags: angular, api, filtering

I'm calling an external api to get data from my angular application. The api returns data according to page number.For eg page 1 returns 20 records. I've a filter in my page which needs to filter data from all of the datasets from all pages. The api returns only next page value and not total pages. How can i achieve my result in this case. Is it necessary to recursively call all pages and store in an array at the beginning or are there any other options. This is one hell of a burden I am facing right now. Can anybody help me on this.

Comment: Please add some code what you have to tried till now.

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek for your interest, Actually i needed the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Well since your API is only giving you the designated objects for a given page and you need data from all pages, you will probably need to load it all.

Although the cleanest way to do it would be to talk to the people who build that API and come to terms with them, the only quite good looking solution for you would be to have either a loading animation (if the request can be done in less than 3 seconds) 
see [Spinner](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/overview) for example,
or to send multiple request in succesion and push your new results onto your page once they come in to show the user, that your app is searching for the results.

Comment: Thankyou Ronald, so i guess loading all the data is the only option